# Discretizing a continuous mathematical equation

Tags: matlab, math

I want to implement a code that shuffles the information inside a cube of size (bs x bs x bs), such that each element inside the cube (x,y,z) is mapped uniquely to (x_new, y_new,z). But the code is not properly working.

[image]

The image attached is the actual mathematical definition of the code which I have tried to discretize and implement. The original mathematical equations work on a unit cube, whereas I have a cube of dimension bs. Can somebody have a look at my code and hint at the supposed bug?

```
n=bs;
NEWI=zeros(bs,bs,bs);
for row= 1:bs
    for col=1:bs 
        for height=1:bs
            if (     1<=row && row<=(n/2) && 1<=col && col<=(n/2) )
                x_new= 2*(row-1) + 1;
                y_new= 2*(col-1) + 1;
                 z=floor(0.25*(height-mod(height-1,2)))+1; 
             end
for 
for
for

Now this is just the first line implementation of the equation given in the figure. But as we see the coorepondence of points 
             (1,1,1) goes to (1,1,1)
              (1,1,2) goes to (1,1,1)
              (1,1,3) goes to  (1,1,1)
               (1,1,4) goes to (1,1,1)
which clearly is not a unique mapping, whereas the function claims of giving unique images for every (x,y,z). So my question is clearly there has to be some adjustments to discretize this map. Can somebody suggest
```

Comment: Why do you think its wrong? Care to explain the differences between your equation and the one you shared? Care to provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: I see one problem, which is that you're multiplying n/2 by 2: `y_new= 2*(col-1-n/2)`. This is the same as saying `y_new = 2*col - 2 - n`, which will always be negative. I think you meant `y_new= 2*(col-1)-n/2`. This mistake is repeated for `x_new` as well. I'm also not sure why you're involving the `height` value's parity in every operation.

Comment: why will it be negative? I have included the condition:    col>n/2,  already

Comment: The equations spread information in the x and y direction by a factor 2, and squeeze it along z by a factor 4. Obviously that cannot work in the discrete world. `z/4` will lead to sub-pixel locations in 3 out of 4 cases. This is why you have 4 values mapping to the same location.

Comment: But the article that i am reading, says that it maps points uniquely.

Answer (score -1):

Some of your condition are unclear:

- Why do you check if `1<=row` if row is always `>=1` ?
- Why are you using a modulo ? (as pointed out by @Welbog)
- ...

But to answer your question, I recommend you to use logical indexing and `meshgrid` it will make your code more readable. And you will be able to do all the operations in one line.

```
% size of your 3D cube
n = 5;
% With meshgrid we generate the 3D grid that we will use to create the logical index.
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(1:n,1:n,1:n);
% Create empty array
M = zeros(n,n,n);
%first condition
I      = x<(n/2) & y<(n/2);        %create a logical index according to the first condition
M(I)   = 2*x(I) + 2*y(I) + z(I)/4; %generate the associated value
%second condition
I      = ...
```

Comment: modulo is for adjusting the indexing in matlabi.e avoiding zero indexes

Comment: I did not understand your answer of using meshgrid